# Add image on the right element list when hover

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items and an image of an arrow.

```
<ul>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>C</li>
   <li>D</li>
   <div class="arrow">
      <img src="./assets/images/Arrow.svg">
   </div>
</ul>
```

How can i make that arrow image appears on the right ***li*** element when hover.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Also, lists (`ol` and `ul`) can only contain `li` as valid children, so that `div` may or may not appear as expected depending on the browser.

Comment: You can introduce an `li::before` pseudo-element and make it visible on `li:hover::before`.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, ::before seems interesting, i'll try it. Could you please post it as an answer, so i can validate.

Answer (score 0):

use `li:hover::after` to add image on hover.

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  font-size: 34px;
  position: relative;
  width: max-content;
}

li:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  font-size: 35px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in;
}

li:hover::after{
  position:absolute;
  content: ">"; /* add url('img_url here') */
  left: calc(100% + 10px);
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>list option : A</li>
   <li>list option : B</li>
   <li>list option : C</li>
   <li>list option : D</li>
</ul>
```